# How to display one model item per page in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnet-compiler

```
@model OnlineExam.Models.CandidateExam.CandidateItem

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    var questionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OnlineExam.Models.AdminQuestionModel.QuestionAndAnswers>>(TempData["questionList"].ToString());
    //var data = questionList as IEnumerable<OnlineExam.Models.AdminQuestionModel.QuestionAndAnswers>;
    var data2 = questionList as List<OnlineExam.Models.AdminQuestionModel.QuestionAndAnswers>; //new stackov
    int examAttemptId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["examAttemptId"].ToString());
    TempData.Keep();

}

<h1>Answer Exam</h1>
<h6>Best of luck!!</h6>
<div>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="AnswerExam">

        @{
            int counter = 0;
        }
        @for (var i = 0; i < data2.Count(); i++)
        {
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="border-light" style="background-color: lavender">
                        @{
                            counter = counter + 1;
                        }
                        <td>Question @counter) @data2[i].Question.ToString()</td>
                        @{
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="candidateExamsList[i].ExamId" value="@data2[i].ExamId" />
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="candidateExamsList[i].QuestionId" value="@data2[i].QuestionId" />
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="candidateExamsList[i].ExamAttemptId" value="@examAttemptId" />
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                    @*<tr class="border-white">
                        <td>Options : </td>
                    </tr>*@
                    <tr class="border-light">
                        <td>a) @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.candidateExamsList[i].OptionSelected, data2[i].OptionOne) @data2[i].OptionOne</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="border-light" style="background-color: lavender">
                        <td>b) @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.candidateExamsList[i].OptionSelected, data2[i].OptionTwo) @data2[i].OptionTwo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="border-light">
                        <td>c) @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.candidateExamsList[i].OptionSelected, data2[i].OptionThree) @data2[i].OptionThree</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="border-light" style="background-color: lavender">
                        <td>d) @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.candidateExamsList[i].OptionSelected, data2[i].OptionFour) @data2[i].OptionFour</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td> </td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Test" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have a list of questions in my model and i wish to display each question (model item) on single page and then click next to move on to next question (model item).

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Hi, You did not state if you want this page to reload?, Also You can used custom tabs if the questions are not much. `aspnet-compiler` tag in question is not necessary

Comment: no i do not wish to reload the page. i wish to manipulate the data on client side.  @Bosco